# Python: counting specific words from HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I'm a Python rookie having quite a hard time learning web scraping. I intend on counting the number of words in this HTML page, and show which words appear only once, as well as how many times the word "ladies" is shown. I've managed to come up with this so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
from collections import Counter

def my_start(url):
   my_wordlist = []
   my_source_code = requests.get(url).text
   my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_source_code, 'html.parser')
   for each_text in my_soup.findAll('p', {'class':'about-text'}):
      content = each_text.text
      words = content.lower().split()
      for each_word in words:
         my_wordlist.append(each_word)
      clean_wordlist(my_wordlist)

def clean_wordlist(wordlist):
   clean_list =[]
   for word in wordlist: 
      symbols = '!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/., '
      for i in range (0, len(symbols)):
         word = word.replace(symbols[i], '')
      if len(word) > 0:
         clean_list.append(word)
   create_dictionary(clean_list)

def create_dictionary(clean_list):
   word_count = {}
   for word in clean_list:
      if word in word_count:
         word_count[word] += 1
      else:
         word_count[word] = 1
   c = Counter(word_count)
   print(c)
   if word_count[word] == 1:
    print(word)
   top = soup.find_all("ladies")
   print(top)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  my_start("http://brasil.pyladies.com/about/")
```

I noticed that there are some words that appear only once that aren't shown here, as well as a word that appears twice and is shown. I can't figure out how to count the number of times the word "ladies" is shown either. Any inputs on the matter will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use regular expressions (`regex`) for solving this problem

```
import re

my_source_code = requests.get(url).text
pattern = "ladies"

ladies_count = len(re.findall(pattern, my_source_code))
```

it is most fast way for counting word from text

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know this library before, it was truly useful!

Comment: You can `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs` and with `BeautifulSoup` extract all text from html content then count. `all_text = bs(content, "html.parser").text` and after this `len(re.find_all(pattern, all_text))` returns result which you needed

Answer (score 1):

`top = soup.find_all("ladies")`

Here the usage of `find_all` is wrong. It is used to search for HTML tags, not words.

If you want to print the number of times the word 'ladies' has appeared, try

```
print(word_count.get('ladies','0'))
```